# Pointing a sub folder to another DNS

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I have a domain name and running in a windows server. Let's call it as www.example.com . My need is to host a blog inside www.example.com/help root. I need the blog to be done in wordpress, my windows server doesn't allow me to host wordpress on it. I have a shared server also and created a domain on that server with the same www.example.com, then created FTP and created a folder inside the Help folder. Now I need to point that to the server. How can I set that, is it possible to point a domain name to 3 DNS?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a subdomain on your windows server with name help. This will create an A record in the DNS Settings there. Go in DNS Settings (depends upon panel there) and edit the help.example.com's A record to the IP of your cPanel Linux server.

Then, on your cPanel server, you need to create a domain name not just example.com, but help.example.com (same as of subdomain whose record you edited). Now install wordpress at cPanel server, and that's it.

Note: IP changes may take a few hours to propagate.

Comment: The above one is an alternative method, i would like to use as a directory. www.example.com/help. Is there any method to use in that way?